# How to use service worker to reload web page?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, service-worker

I have setup a php page with html which should be reloaded every 10 seconds and check the php code if there is a new database entry.
The whole thing work, but not on mobile. I want that the website even refresh after the user is leaving the browser or locking the screen. So the only solution which seems to be usable is service worker.
I tried web worker, but the javascript refresh code doesnt work.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.reload(1);
}, 10000);
```

I really just need that the service worker is reloading the website.

I hope you can help
Thanks

Comment: Rather than reloading the entire page every second, you might want to look into using AJAX to ask a PHP file to check if there is a new database entry, and if so send back a truthy value. Only *then*, if there is a new entry, should you reload the page (or *just the part of the page that needs to change*)

Comment: but is AJAX solving the issue that the site is running in the background?
The website reloading is not the problem, due everything else will be stored in cache. So its just the PHP site which has to be reloaded.

Comment: I got it working with XHR, that works fine, but still cause the problem, that after minimizing the browser on mobile or locking the screen, it doesnt will work.